# laravel query builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel, builder

I want to write sql query

```
SELECT
  *,
  SUM(item_quantity)
FROM sales
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY SUM(item_quantity)  DESC LIMIT 5
```

On laravel query builder but failed.
Can anyone please help me.

I use Model() instead of DB.

Comment: share the code you've wrote, and error output as well

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking the following solution:

```
$sales = Sales::select('*', 'SUM(item_quantity) as total_item_qnty')
            ->groupBy('item_id')
            ->orderBy('total_item_qnty', 'desc')
            ->take(5)
```

Try this code

Comment: Thnks Bilas 4 ur answr. i have edited ur code. now its works very well.
$sales = Sales::select('*',
DB::raw('SUM(item_quantity) as total_item_qnty'))
            ->groupBy
('item_id')
            ->orderBy
('total_item_qnty', 'desc')
            ->take(5)->get();